# mongodb unable to solve silly thing - having issue with mongodb updating the entry

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I want to update the entry at mongodb database I am using atlas cluster.

While updating in local(Local mongodb) with code it works like charm!

But when I do with cluster its not working. but at same when I try to update the cluster one with terminal then it works well. not sure what's wront.

here's my code

```
const savedData = await db.collection('data').update({ _id: mongo.ObjectID(_id) }, {
      $set: {
        DataDetails: {
          AccountId: data.account_id.toString(),
          UniqueId: data.data.unique_id.toString(),
          DataId: data.data.id.toString(),
          // createdAt: new Date(),
        }
      }
  });
    return savedData;
```

Debuggning this, I have been consoling the `savedData` at logs, Now the local database returns

```
result: { n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 },
  connection: Connection {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      error: [Function],
      close: [Function],
      timeout: [Function],
      parseError: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    options: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 27017,
      size: 5,
      connectionTimeout: 30000,
      socketTimeout: 360000,
      keepAlive: true,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 300000,
      noDelay: true,
```

but the cluster one returns

```
CommandResult {
  result: {
    n: 0,
    nModified: 0,
    opTime: { ts: [Timestamp], t: 65 },
    electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000041,
    ok: 1,
    operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1634236388 },
    '$clusterTime': { clusterTime: [Timestamp], signature: [Object] }
  },
  connection: Connection {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      error: [Function],
      close: [Function],
      timeout: [Function],
      parseError: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined
```

Not sure why this is happening at first place, and not sure how to resolve this?
Stuck at this point since along time.
Please help.

Comment: That kind of looks like it might not be connected or not connected to a primary?

Comment: Feeling stupid to ask, but what is primary? Like what you mean from primary?

Comment: When you have a mongo cluster, one node is the "primary" which is the main source of truth and the one you write into. The others are for reading only, usually, and might be slightly "behind" the primary regarding changes.

Comment: Are you sure that particular document you are trying to update exists on the cluster? Are you able to perform any other operations on the cluster?